# What is the geometrical interpretation of $1 - i \cdot \text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = z$ in the Gaussian number plane?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the geometrical interpretation of $1 - i \cdot \text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = z$ in the Gaussian number plane?

I get that the first part is the real part 1 with no imaginary part so it lies on the real axis, so it basically means I have a point that is at 1 on the real axis and dependent on the value of z I transform it so it is equal to point z? The last part is what I do not get.

Comment: Rewrite $z=x+i y$ and equate the real and imaginary parts of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$. Then $\dfrac{1}{z}=\dfrac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$. So $\operatorname{Im}\left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)=\dfrac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$. The given condition implies $$\begin{cases}x&=1\\y&=\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2}\end{cases}$$
This means $y(y^2+1)-y=0$, so $y=0$. The geometric representation of this is thus a single point $(1,0)$.

Comment: There is a wrong sign in the first line. It is $1/z=(x-iy)/(x^2+y^2)$.